# opencv_traincascade apparently stops in the middle of train

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, training-data, haar-classifier, adaboost

I'm doing some tests into `traincascade`, and I saw that in starts of train, the process uses all power of processor, and after a few hours or days apparently stops, because the processor usage doesn't pass 30%. Is it normal? In output, nothing about error occurs, just my observation in processor usage.

I using 1000 positive images with 128x128, and 3000 negative images with 1920x1280. I saw in some places about dimension, but I wanted to try with that because my images to detect the object has this dimension.

Do I need to decrease that and in the detection do I need to apply a scale matrix or my process has something wrong and thus it stops?

Comment: what's the acceptance ration of the previous step? Does it "stop" in the "searching for negative samples" part of the current stage? Did you compile openCV with TBB?

Comment: Hi Micka, eht acceptance ration in previous step is  acceptanceRatio    2260 : 4.471e-05. Yes I compile with TBB, so the algorithm "stop" showing NEG current samples: 495, and after that NEG current samples: and show nothing

Comment: does it completely stop (no new negative sample since many hours)? When I started my first cascade trainings I sometimes accidentally activated "quick edit mode" in my windows console window by clicking inside of it, which will pause the current application and resumes on hitting "return". But maybe you just don't have any negatives left, so no more can be found.

Comment: thank you Micka, about pause, in my case i fink isn't possible becouse I running on a remote computer by ssh command line, but you help me so much I will go provide more negative samples

Comment: Hi, just to update, im my previous answer my train shows NEG current samples: 495 now NEG current samples: 822. Do you think I let it continue or stop and provide new negative images?